# Django: How to force the loop in template to display a field only once

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to force the '*name*' field in a model to display only once in a for loop in a django template.

Here's my Models:

```
class add_engineering_course(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='Computer Engineering')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name



class add_engineering_course_information(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(add_engineering_course)
    university = models.ForeignKey(engineeringUni)
    campus = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='Campus')
    fees = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name.name

    def university_a(self):
        return self.university

    def campus_a(self):
        return self.campus

    def fees_a(self):
        return str(self.fees)
```

My Views:

```
def abc_list(request):
    abc_listing = add_engineering_course_information.objects.order_by('id')
    return render(request, 'theproject/testing.html', {'abc_listing': abc_listing})
```

My Template:

```
    {% for x in abc_listing %}
  {{ x.name }}<br>
  Unviserity: {{ x.university_a }}<br>
  Campus: {{ x.campus_a }}<br>
  Fees: {{ x.fees_a }}<br><br><br>

{% endfor %}
```

The above code results in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKf2X.png) (image).

As you can see in the image, the name `x.name` is appearing multiple times (depending upon the entry).

example: **Network Engineering** is appearing two times because there are two different universities added into its category.

What I want is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0J1VE.png) (image).

The `x.name` should only appear once and the rest of the things (university, campus, fees) should display as normal (multiple times depending upon how many are there).

Comment: The better way is to structure your data inside the `view` like `x.name` can be a key of dictionary and that can hold list of values i.e universities in your case. On template outer loop can iterate over dictionary and inner loop over the list.

Comment: @anuragal Well this looks that It might solve the problem, Can you show any code example (or docs reference) of structuring data like `x.name` inside a view.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, you ought to define category as a separate model to course information. Create a many-to-one relationship between the models. You can then proceed to use two `for` loops. In the first (outer loop), iterate over the set of categories. In the second (inner loop), iterate over the set of courses belonging to each category. The [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/) offers a nice walkthrough on many-to-one relationships between models.

Comment: Can you provide a code example for this?
I tried to do it by changing my views to 
https://pastebin.com/dq5MrHMj

and changing the template too but It shows name (Category) but then displays all the universities (all universities even the one which is not in that category.